# Topological conjugacy of flows from general linear ODEs

Tags: general-topology, ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request, dynamical-systems

Consider two linear systems of ODEs, $\dot{x}=Ax$ and $\dot{y}=By$ for $x,y \in \mathbb{R}^d$. Their associated flows, $F^t$ and $G^t$, are *linearly conjugate* if there exists a linear homeomorphism $T : \mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}^d$ such that $TG^t(x) = F^t(Tx)$ for all $x,t$. It is known that two $F,G$ are linearly conjugate iff $A,B$ are similar. Further, Kocak and Hale provide results for the general (i.e. not necessarily linear) topological conjugacy of linear systems on the plane.

**My question:** When are the flows associated to two linear systems of ODEs generally topologically conjugate in general dimensions ($d>2$)?